# robot.mousepress "Auto Clicker" How to make it stop?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have found code to make an Auto-Clicker for recreational use.

What code would I use to make the clicker stop? I was hoping to use something like A Key listener to make it stop. Like by pressing space and enter to make it start and stop.

Here is the code :

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class AutoClicker {

public static int rate = 0;

public static void main (String[] args) {

    while (rate == 0){
        try{
            System.out.println("Speed of the auto-clicker (in miliseconds):");
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
             try {
                rate = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                if (rate < 500) {
                    rate = 0;
                    System.out.println("Must be at least 500 miliseconds.");
             }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error - please try again.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}

}
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(rate);
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        } 
    }catch (AWTException e) {}
}

}
```

Comment: I'm just curious about it: how does and auto-clicker can be used for recreation?

Comment: It could be used to click while playing a game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
While(true)
```

Use

```
While(//keyevent here// != true)
```

So until you press the button specified by you, it will continue looping, once the keyevent equals true the autoclicker will stop.